# Is it possible to assert that a node is scrollable in jetpack compose testing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, android-jetpack-compose-testing

Is it possible to assert that a jetpack compose node is scrollable when performing tests?

```
class MyTest {
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun givenEnoughItems_thenAssertListIsScrollable() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            BasicTheme {
                ScrollableComponent(items = List(1000) { "$it" })
            }
        }

        composeTestRule.onRoot().fetchSemanticsNode().assertIsScrollable()
    }
}

fun SemanticsNodeInteraction.assertIsScrollable() : SemanticsNodeInteraction {
    // What would go here? 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `hasScrollAction()`.

**Example**

```
import androidx.compose.ui.test.hasScrollAction
import androidx.compose.ui.test.assert

private fun assertNodeIsScrollable() {
    findNode().assert(hasScrollAction())
}
```

and `findNode()` would be something like

```
private fun findNode(): SemanticsNodeInteraction {
    return composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(
        testTag = "test_tag",
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasScrollAction()` along with `performScrollToIndex()`:

```kotlin
@Test
fun checkThatElementCanScroll() {
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        BasicTheme {
            ScrollableComponent(items = List(1000) { "$it" })
        }
    }

    composeTestRule
        .onNodeWithTag("ScrollableItemTag", useUnmergedTree = true)
        .assert(hasScrollAction())
    composeTestRule
        .onNodeWithTag("ScrollableItemTag", useUnmergedTree = true)
        .performScrollToIndex(20)
}
```